# Javascript -> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, appendchild

I have a few arrays consisting of hex values and image urls.

```
var envelope_colors_array = [
            '#feebe4',
            '#abd076',
            '#b8d9d5'...

var metallic_envelope_spans_array = [
            'color 1',
            'color 2',
            'color 3'...

var envelope_img_src_array = [
            '/images/envelopes/envelope.png',
            '/images/envelopes/envelope.png',
            '/images/envelopes/envelope.png'...
```

With these I'm trying to create divs, each with a unique child img element and a span element sibling to the div. Then each of these divs and spans should be appended to a list item element.

```
var metallic_envelope_images_array = metallic_envelope_img_src_array.map(function(img_src, index, metallic_envelope_img_src_array) {
        var metallic_envelope_image = document.createElement('IMG');
        metallic_envelope_image.style.width = '100px';
        metallic_envelope_image.style.height = '74px';
        metallic_envelope_image.onload = function(){
          metallic_envelope_image.src = metallic_envelope_img_src_array[index];
        }
        return metallic_envelope_image;
      });


      var metallic_envelope_divs_array = metallic_envelope_colors_array.map(function(color, index, metallic_envelope_colors_array) {
        var metallic_envelope_div = document.createElement('DIV');
        metallic_envelope_div.style.width = '100px';
        metallic_envelope_div.style.height = '74px';
        metallic_envelope_div.style.backgroundColor = metallic_envelope_colors_array[index];
        return metallic_envelope_div;
      });


      var metallic_envelope_chart_spans_array = metallic_envelope_spans_array.map(function(span, index, metallic_envelope_spans_array){
        var metallic_envelope_span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        metallic_envelope_span.style.display = 'block';
        metallic_envelope_span.style.textAlign = 'center';
        var metallic_envelope_span_text_node = document.createTextNode(metallic_envelope_spans_array[index]);
        metallic_envelope_span.appendChild(metallic_envelope_span_text_node);
        return metallic_envelope_span;
      });


      var metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array = metallic_envelope_divs_array.map(function(div, index, metallic_envelope_divs_array){
        var metallic_envelope_div_with_image = metallic_envelope_divs_array[index].appendChild(metallic_envelope_images_array[index]);
        return metallic_envelope_div_with_image;
      });
      console.log("metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array: " + metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array);

      var metallic_envelope_chart_list_items = metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array.map(function(div_with_image, index, metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array){
        var metallic_envelope_li = document.createElement('LI');
        metallic_envelope_li.style.width = '100px';
        metallic_envelope_li.style.height = '74px';
        metallic_envelope_li.style.marginRight = '40px';
        metallic_envelope_li.style.display = 'inline-block';
        metallic_envelope_li.style.listStyleType = "none";
        metallic_envelope_li.appendChild(metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array[index]);
        metallic_envelope_li.appendChild(metallic_envelope_chart_spans_array[index]);
        return metallic_envelope_li;
      });
```

Unfortunately, when the list item element attempts to append the div element, I get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Learn about `.map` so you don't have to use IIFE's and loops: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map .

Comment: just a wild guess: it's not `envelope_divs_with_images[i]`? Because I believe that `envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array` is the function variable, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Felix, I rewrote everything using map, but got the same error, only now it's further down the child-appending line, so to speak. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Gerardo, I don't think this would be an issue since I'm using the same variable name in the next function to append it. I see where that could cause some confusion though.

Comment: If you `console.log(envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array)`, what do you see?

Comment: metallic_envelope_chart_divs_with_images_array: [object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: It doesn't appear to be appending the img elements to the div elements...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues here the code works if you fix that indexes start from 0. Look at [codepen](http://codepen.io/fsacer/pen/MewWJq) and open console and type `envelope_chart_list_items[0]`. It works at least on Safari. Also `for..in` loop is not intended for collections (it iterates through properties) which might have caused issues for you. Consider using `for..of` from ES2015, if you can.